# how to textract &client= from url?

Tags: javascript, url

If my url is `http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http://could-be-any-url.com&name=123456789101112` using **purely javascript** how would I extract `&client=` so it would extract `123456789101112` and set it as `var clientid = 123456789101112;`

Comment: Is it `client` or `name` GET param?

Comment: If you want a more general purpose solution that can fetch any query parameter, go to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript.  I happen to like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/3855394#3855394 in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var clientid = (window.location.search.match(/[?&;]name=(\d+)/) || [])[1];
```

If it can contain more than numbers, use something like...

```
var clientid = (window.location.search.match(/[?&;]name=([^&;]+)/) || [])[1];
```

If the param could not be found, it will return `undefined`.

If you need to do this more often, you'd be better off with a [generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901119#901119).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var url = "http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http://could-be-any-url.com&name=123456789101112"

var name = url.substring(url.indexOf('&name='), url.length)
```

If you don't want to user regular expression like the other answer

Comment: What if there are other GET params after `name` ?

Comment: And also what if name is the first parameter?  Then it won't be preceded by an `&` character.

Comment: Alex and aroth, i would do this : url.substring(url.indexOf('name='), url.indexOf(url.indexOf('name='),'&')) so it look for what is between "name=" and "&"

Answer (score 0):

For a more generic/reusable solution, you can use something like:

```
getParameter = function(paramName, url) {
    if (! paramName) {
        return null;
    }
    if (! url) {
        url = window.location.href;
    }
    if (url.indexOf('?') == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    url = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1);
    var params = url.split('&');
    for (var index = 0; index < params.length; index++) {
        var nameValue = params[index].split('=');
        if (nameValue.length == 2 && nameValue[0] == paramName) {
            return nameValue[1];
        }
    }

    return null;
};
```

...then just call `getParameter('client');`.

Example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/L7hbT/3/

Comment: To be fully compatible with the spec, you should split on `/[&;]/`.

Answer (score 0):

Not as succinct as @alex, but you could do this

```
var a = 'http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http://could-be-any-url.com&name=123456789101112';

var b = a.indexOf('name=');

var clientId = a.substring(b + 5);

alert(clientId);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ubJe3/