# extracting src and setting as href value...after ?url= and before &addclient=

Tags: javascript, jquery, src

If my url is `http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http://stackoverflow.com/`
The code below extracts `http://stackoverflow.com/`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(main);

function main()
{
    $('#download, #imggg').attr('href', getIframeUrl() );
    registerEvents();
    resizeIframe();
}

function getIframeUrl()
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    var iframe_url = 'http://link-ads.blogspot.com/';
    var param_start = url.indexOf("url=");
    if( param_start != -1 ) 
        iframe_url = url.substr(param_start+4,url.length-param_start-4);
    if( iframe_url.indexOf("http://") == -1) 
        iframe_url = "http://" + iframe_url;

    return iframe_url;
}
  </script>
```

my problem is if the url is `http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http://stackoverflow.com/&adclient=12345678kkk1112` the code will extract the url as `http://stackoverflow.com/&adclient=12345678kkk1112` when I want the url before `&adclient=` meaning I only want it to extract `http://stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: You could use the [same code you received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910549/how-to-textract-client-from-url/7910577#7910577) 30 minutes ago.

Comment: I don't know if I want to post it twice, but you can delete your question if you feel it is a duplicate.

Comment: `if (link.substr(0, 7) !== 'http://') { link = 'http://' + link; }`.

Comment: how do i implement it in this ?  `<script>
var urll = (window.location.search.match(/[?&;]url=([^&;]+)/) || [])[1];
document.write('<a href="http://'+urll+'" id="download" class="button" style="display: none;">continue</a>');
</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a regular expression:

```
var url = "http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http://stackoverflow.com/&adclient=12345678kkk1112"
url.match(/url=([^&]+)/)[1]
```

Comment: would you know how to implement this `if (link.substr(0, 7) !== 'http://') { link = 'http://' + link; }` into this `<script> var urll = (window.location.search.match(/[?&;]url=([^&;]+)/) || [])[1]; document.write('<a href="http://'+urll+'" id="download" class="button" style="display: none;">continue</a>'); </script>`